# Running Docker In a 32 Bit Computer

Tags: 32-bit, docker

this might be a weird question.

But I´m running docker in a 32 bit computer, it has 12 years, the main purpose of running docker and linux in that computer is to use it as a server and be able to connect to it using vpn. But I'm a little concerned if this might damage the CPU, the specs of my computer are:

```
OS: LUbuntu 18.04
CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) 2 Duo @ 1.66GHz
Archi: i686
RAM: 4 GB
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not aware of any Core2Duo CPUs that are x86/i686 only, they are x86_64/amd64 in my experience (the 32-bit is likely because you installed a x86/i386/i686 OS)

Comment: You are correct, It is a 64bit processor. All my life I thought it was 32bit. Thank you